# Nested QEMU-KVM hanging with `watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 134s!` kernel messages

Tags: linux, qemu, linux-kvm

I have an issue with QEMU-KVM on Ubuntu Server 22.04 running another QEMU-KVM virtual machine.

First VM is launched via libvirt-based Virtual Machine Manager in privileged mode via following command as seen in `ps -A -o pid,tty,etime,user,cmd | grep qemu`.

```bash
1578678 ?              02:28 root     /usr/lib/qemu/virtiofsd --fd=38 -o source=/home/odisharia_g@edws.local/work/109Server
1578694 ?              02:27 libvirt+ /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name guest=obmchost-session,debug-threads=on -S -object {"qom-type":"secret","id":"masterKey0","format":"raw","file":"/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-2-obmchost-session/master-key.aes"} -machine pc-q35-6.2,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off,memory-backend=pc.ram -accel kvm -cpu host,migratable=on -m 8192 -object {"qom-type":"memory-backend-memfd","id":"pc.ram","share":true,"x-use-canonical-path-for-ramblock-id":false,"size":8589934592} -overcommit mem-lock=off -smp 8,sockets=8,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 3bcc155f-f5a6-4f79-8025-ace56672b355 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=37,server=on,wait=off -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay -no-hpet -no-shutdown -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device pcie-root-port,port=16,chassis=1,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x2 -device pcie-root-port,port=17,chassis=2,id=pci.2,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x1 -device pcie-root-port,port=18,chassis=3,id=pci.3,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x2 -device pcie-root-port,port=19,chassis=4,id=pci.4,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x3 -device pcie-root-port,port=20,chassis=5,id=pci.5,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x4 -device pcie-root-port,port=21,chassis=6,id=pci.6,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x5 -device pcie-root-port,port=22,chassis=7,id=pci.7,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x6 -device pcie-root-port,port=23,chassis=8,id=pci.8,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x7 -device pcie-root-port,port=24,chassis=9,id=pci.9,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x3 -device pcie-root-port,port=25,chassis=10,id=pci.10,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x1 -device pcie-root-port,port=26,chassis=11,id=pci.11,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x2 -device pcie-root-port,port=27,chassis=12,id=pci.12,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x3 -device pcie-root-port,port=28,chassis=13,id=pci.13,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x4 -device pcie-root-port,port=29,chassis=14,id=pci.14,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x5 -device qemu-xhci,p2=15,p3=15,id=usb,bus=pci.3,addr=0x0 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0 -blockdev {"driver":"file","filename":"/home/odisharia_g@edws.local/work/109Server/158/vm/host/ubuntu22.04-host.qcow2","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-1-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-1-storage","backing":null} -device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,drive=libvirt-1-format,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -chardev socket,id=chr-vu-fs0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-2-obmchost-session/fs0-fs.sock -device vhost-user-fs-pci,id=fs0,chardev=chr-vu-fs0,tag=/mnt/host-work-sources,bus=pci.1,addr=0x0 -netdev tap,fd=38,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=40 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:3b:01:02,bus=pci.2,addr=0x0 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,fd=36,server=on,wait=off -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel1,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=2,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0,bus=usb.0,port=1 -audiodev {"id":"audio1","driver":"spice"} -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing=on,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1 -device ich9-intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1b -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0,audiodev=audio1 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.6,addr=0x0 -object {"qom-type":"rng-random","id":"objrng0","filename":"/dev/urandom"} -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=objrng0,id=rng0,bus=pci.7,addr=0x0 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
1578716 ?              02:27 root     /usr/lib/qemu/virtiofsd --fd=38 -o source=/home/odisharia_g@edws.local/work/109Server
```

Inside that VM I manually try to run another VM with the following script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd -- "$(dirname "$0")" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P )"
 
export LC_ALL=C
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export HOME="$SCRIPTPATH/../vm/bmc"
export XDG_DATA_HOME="$HOME/.local/share"
export XDG_CACHE_HOME="$HOME/.cache"
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none
 
_boot_once=""
 
# shellcheck disable=2154
while getopts ":b" _opt; do
    case "$_opt" in
        "b")
            _boot_once="-boot once=d"
            ;;
        "?")
            printf "Invalid option: -%s" "$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
 
_uuid="$(uuid)"
 
for _direction in "in" "out"; do
    [ ! -p "$HOME/ipmi-$_direction.pipe" ] && mkfifo "$HOME/ipmi-$_direction.pipe"
done
 
#    -chardev socket,path="$HOME/i2c-0.sock0",id=virt-i2c-0 \
#    -device vhost-user-i2c-pci,chardev=virt-i2c-0,id=i2c-0 \
#    \
# Example is here: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/06/configure-and-run-a-qemu-based-vm-outside-of-libvirt#create_a_boot_script_from_the_qemu_command
# TODO: networks... 
# shellcheck disable=2140
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -name BMC-Ubuntu-22.04.3,debug-threads=on \
    -machine pc-q35-6.2,accel=kvm,dump-guest-core=off,vmport=off,hmat=on \
    -cpu host,hypervisor=on \
    -m 6144M \
    -object memory-backend-file,id=mem,size=6G,mem-path=/dev/shm,share=on \
    -numa node,memdev=mem \
    -overcommit mem-lock=off \
    -smp 2,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=1,maxcpus=2 \
    -device i6300esb \
    -uuid "$_uuid" \
    -no-user-config \
    -nodefaults \
    -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path="$HOME/monitor.sock",server=on,telnet=on,mux=on,wait=off \
    -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=readline \
    -chardev socket,id=qmpmonitor,path="$HOME/monitor-qmp.sock",server=on,wait=off \
    -mon chardev=qmpmonitor,id=qmp_chardev,mode=control,pretty=on \
    -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew \
    -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard \
    -no-shutdown \
    -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
    -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 \
    \
    -device pcie-root-port,port=0x10,chassis=1,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x2 \
    -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.1,addr=0x0 \
    -serial mon:telnet::4444,server=on,wait=off \
    \
    -device pcie-root-port,port=0x11,chassis=2,id=pci.2,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x1 \
    -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial1,bus=pci.2,addr=0x0 \
    -serial mon:telnet::4445,server=on,wait=off \
    \
    -device pcie-root-port,port=0x12,chassis=3,id=pci.3,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x2 \
    -netdev bridge,id=bridgenet0,br=qemu-br0 \
    -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=bridgenet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:2d:4f,bus=pci.3,addr=0x0 \
    \
    -drive file="$SCRIPTPATH/../images/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso",index=0,media=cdrom \
    \
    -device pcie-root-port,port=0x13,chassis=4,id=pci.4,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x3 \
    -drive file="$HOME/bmc-x86_64.qcow2",format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,index=1,aio=threads \
    -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0 \
    \
    -chardev socket,id="chr-vu-host-fs0",path="$HOME/host-fs0.sock" \
    -device pcie-root-port,port=0x14,chassis=5,id=pci.5,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x4 \
    -device vhost-user-fs-pci,id="host-fs0",chardev=chr-vu-host-fs0,tag="/host/work-sources",bus=pci.5,addr=0x0 \
    \
    -chardev pipe,id=pipe_ch0,path="$HOME/ipmi-in.pipe" \
    -device virtserialport,chardev=pipe_ch0,name=serial0 \
    \
    -chardev pipe,id=pipe_ch1,path="$HOME/ipmi-out.pipe" \
    -device virtserialport,chardev=pipe_ch1,name=serial1 \
    \
    -msg timestamp=on \
    $_boot_once \
    -display none \
    -nographic \
```

I try to install OS onto it and sometimes, or when I install some compiled software fro virtiofs-based FS inside nested VM, it hangs with following kernel messages:

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 134s!
```

Only reboot helps.

I used option `softlockup_panic=1` for kernel to get panic with stacktrace, and got following stacktrace (only this I can get from tmux, terminal is messed with Ubuntu installation UI):

```
[   88.672579] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000001000
[   88.672579] RDX: ffffe8bf47846200 RSI: ffff99ad984c6500 RDI: ffff99ae61188000
[   88.672579] RBP: ffffbccc40b5ba38 R08: ffffe8bf47846240 R09: 0000000000000001
[   88.672579] R10: 0000000000000293 R11: ffff99ae79d366e0 R12: ffff99ae7ffd6b80
[   88.672579] R13: 0000000000000901 R14: ffff99ae7ffd7cc0 R15: 0000000000000000
[   88.672579] FS:  00007f99a54be740(0000) GS:ffff99ae79d00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   88.672579] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   88.672579] CR2: 0000562f966e7580 CR3: 000000011430a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[   88.672579] PKRU: 55555554
[   88.672579] Call Trace:
[   88.672579]  <TASK>
[   88.672579]  ? kernel_init_free_pages.part.0+0x4a/0x70
[   88.672579]  get_page_from_freelist+0x353/0x540
[   88.672579]  ? _copy_to_iter+0xd7/0x710
[   88.672579]  __alloc_pages+0x17e/0x330
[   88.672579]  alloc_pages+0x9e/0x1e0
[   88.672579]  __page_cache_alloc+0x7e/0x90
[   88.672579]  pagecache_get_page+0x152/0x590
[   88.672579]  grab_cache_page_write_begin+0x21/0x40
[   88.672579]  ext4_da_write_begin+0xec/0x2c0
[   88.672579]  generic_perform_write+0xc6/0x200
[   88.672579]  ? file_update_time+0x66/0x140
[   88.672579]  ext4_buffered_write_iter+0xac/0x180
[   88.672579]  ext4_file_write_iter+0x43/0x60
[   88.672579]  new_sync_write+0x111/0x1a0
[   88.672579]  vfs_write+0x1d5/0x270
[   88.672579]  ksys_write+0x67/0xf0
[   88.672579]  __x64_sys_write+0x19/0x20
[   88.672579]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
[   88.672579]  ? ksys_lseek+0x85/0xc0
[   88.672579]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
[   88.672579]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
[   88.672579]  ? __x64_sys_lseek+0x18/0x20
[   88.672579]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
[   88.672579]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
[   88.672579]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
[   88.672579] RIP: 0033:0x7f99a55d5a37
[   88.672579] Code: 10 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b7 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24
[   88.672579] RSP: 002b:00007ffdcf317098 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[   88.672579] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f99a55d5a37
[   88.672579] RDX: 0000000000000400 RSI: 000055ce0b672e80 RDI: 0000000000000001
[   88.672579] RBP: 0000000000000400 R08: 0000000000000400 R09: 00000000000ffffe
[   88.672579] R10: 000000000000000f R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000400
[   88.672579] R13: 000055ce0b672e80 R14: 0000000000008000 R15: 000055ce0b672e80
[   88.672579]  </TASK>
[   88.668575] Shutting down cpus with NMI
[   88.668575] Kernel Offset: 0xec00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   88.668575] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: softlockup: hung tasks ]---
```

What am I doing wrong and how to get stable nested VM inside my main VM?

My host bare metal system is Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3.

`uname -a`

```
Linux georgyodisharia-workstation 6.2.0-1003-nvidia #3~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed May 31 15:37:08 UTC 20 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lscpu`

```
`Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          24
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-23
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
Model name:                      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           151
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              16
Socket(s):                       1
Stepping:                        2
CPU max MHz:                     5200,0000
CPU min MHz:                     800,0000
BogoMIPS:                        6374.40
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req hfi umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq tme rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize pconfig arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       640 KiB (16 instances)
L1i cache:                       768 KiB (16 instances)
L2 cache:                        14 MiB (10 instances)
L3 cache:                        30 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA node(s):                    1
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-23
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
```

`lsmem`

```
RANGE                                  SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE  BLOCK
0x0000000000000000-0x0000000037ffffff  896M online       yes    0-6
0x0000000100000000-0x00000008bfffffff   31G online       yes 32-279

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:    31,9G
Total offline memory:      0B
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with a single VM (no nested virtualization). When virtiofs mounts are present, the system frequently freezes completely for a few seconds. I have now removed virtiofs and replaced it by network sharing and the issues have disappeared. Host is Debian bookworm, guest disk and virtiofs are backed by ZFS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are overcommiting CPU and the CPUs on your host are busy/blocked by other VMs, so your VM's vCPU is irresponsive for some seconds.